# I have a table Claims with a 1-N relation to an Invoice table, I need to find all claims for which its invoices have a certain value, in SQL

Tags: sql, sqlite

Claim table has columns: id   NUMBER, claim_presented_on DATE

Invoices table has columns: id NUMBER, fkey_Response  NUMBER, fkey_claim     NUMBER

I want to have all claims for which at least one of its invoices have a fkey_Response value of 1.

The SQL code is something like this (but not this, I am beginner to SQL:

```
select
   c.id,
   (
      SELECT count(*) > 0
       from Invoices q
      WHERE q.fkey_claim = c.id
        and q.fkey_INSResponse = 1
   )
from
   Invoices i
INNER JOIN
   Claims c
      on i.fkey_claim = c.id_claim
```

Can someone give me some light here please?

Thanks

Comment: However you choose to layout your code, all on one single line is possibly the worst choice.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand it, you don't actually want any data from the invoices, you just want to check that at least one invoice exists with a specific response.

That being the case, you can use `EXISTS()`, which just checks whether a sub-subquery returns ***at least*** one row or not.

```
SELECT
  c.*
FROM
  Claims c
WHERE
  EXISTS (
    SELECT *
      FROM Invoices i
     WHERE i.fkey_claim = c.id
       AND i.fkey_INSResponse = 1
  )
```

To show ***all*** claims, and the number of invoices with a desired response, you can join on a sub-query...

```
SELECT
  c.*,
  ISNULL(i.response_1_count, 0)  AS response_1_count
FROM
  Claims c
LEFT JOIN
(
    SELECT fkey_claim, COUNT(*) AS response_1_count
      FROM Invoices
     WHERE fkey_INSResponse = 1
  GROUP BY fkey_claim
)
  AS i
    ON i.fkey_claim = c.id
```

Comment: Not quite but thank you! The goal is to list Claim.id together with a boolean value indicating whether this Claim has at least one Invoice for which Invoice.fkey_INSResponse is 1.

Comment: This looks correct to me.  You should better explain the issue you are having with it.

Comment: @JuanDent - Please edit your question and elaborate on what you need.  Ideally giving example input data and desired results.

Comment: This can happen: Several Invoice instances where fkey_INSResponse has values 1 or above. The desired output should contain a listing that includes the Claim.id and whether that Claim has at least ONE Invoice with fkey_INSResponse equal to 1

Comment: @JuanDent - ***Please edit your question and elaborate on what you need. Ideally giving example input data and desired results*** : https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Thank you all for your help!! We can close this issue